# How to make Abstract in double-spacing

Tags: line-spacing, abstract

I am using the [Easy Thesis](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/thesis/easy-thesis/) template to write my thesis.

I want my abstract to be in double spacing.

By default this template has an environment for "abstract" in the class file.

```
\newenvironment{abstract}
{
    \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{center}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    {\Large{\bf{ABSTRACT}} \par}
    \medskip
  \end{center}
}
```

I have tried to use the command `\linespread{1.6}\selectfont` in the environment above and in the `abstract.tex` file. Unfortunately, nothing happens. I did not get double spacing.

Can I get some help on how to go about this?

Appreciate any help.

I also browse website but solution is given for memoir class and not for Thesis.cls.

Comment: Try `\baselineskip=2em` for example, inside the `center`.

Comment: Nothing happen...

Comment: OK. #Sigur it works if I place the command after the end{center}. Thank you. Just for verification, is 2em=double spacing ?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. The command should be outside `center` to have effect on the abstract contents. `em` is the width of the capital `M` in the current font. So it changes automatically when you change the font. Of course you can use another units, but I like that. Usually I use `1.5em`.

Comment: you can try `\baselineskip=2\baselineskip`

Comment: It should work if you put `\linespread{1.6}\selectfont` just after `\end{center}`

Comment: @egreg Answer or close? Looking at the template and especially the abstract in the frontmatter dir, i feel goose bumps on my back.

Comment: @Johannes_B Close.